# How to protect rabbitmq passwords when using rascal config file on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I'm trying to implement a `NodeJS` microservice, and I need it to use `RabbitMQ`.
For the rabbit integration, I'm using '**rascal**' (https://github.com/guidesmiths/rascal) since it solves lots of my concerns out of the box.
I noticed that rascal is driven by a config file where you declare the rabbit URL, username, password, and more.

My question is, what is the best practice for protecting those passwords in the rascal config file so it will be

a) not be pushed to git

b) not be exposed so easily

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that loading secrets as environment variables. Rather than JSON, Rascal configurations can also be defined as JavaScript files ([see the example from Rascal's repository](https://github.com/guidesmiths/rascal/tree/master/examples/advanced)). Then, secrets can be accessed inside of  config file at runtime via **process.env.<SECRET_NAME>**.

Answer (score 0):

Use amqplib npm module to use a rabbitmq integration on nodejs.
I give sample publish consume code on rabbitmq.

**Publish code:**

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://username:password@localhost:5672', function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;


    connection.createChannel(function(err, channel) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var exchange = 'data';

        var msg = "Welcome to Node and rabbitMQ";

        channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'fanout', {
            durable: false
        })
        channel.publish(exchange, '', Buffer.from(msg));
        console.log(msg)
    })

})
```

**Consume Code**

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://username:password@localhost:5672', function(err0, connection) {
    if (err0) throw err0;
    connection.createChannel(function(err1, channel) {
        if (err1) throw err1;
        var exchange = 'data';
        channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'fanout', { durable: false })
        channel.assertQueue('', {
            exclusive: true
        }, function(err2, value) {
            channel.bindQueue(value.queue, exchange, '');

            channel.consume(value.queue, function(msg) {
                console.log("message:", msg.content.toString())

            }, { noAck: true })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: thank you, but as mentioned, I know amqp but would like to work with rascal since it resolved lots of concerns I have that amqp does not resolve.

Comment: ok sorry i know  only amqp.